# Alternative jquery code or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given that you have an HTML table that has 3 columns and you want the first two columns to be of different font size say small and the last or 3rd column to be of medium size. Now, I have a lot of rows in that column say 10 rows which mean i have 30 `<td>` elements (3 x 10). Now I don't want to put a class name for each `<td>` of the first two columns that would have a small size font and the 3rd column again with medium size font. But I don't want to create class attribute/property for each TD just to achieve that. So, I created a jquery to do that like the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.secondtable td').each(function(index) {
    if ((index+1)%3==0) {
      $(this).addClass("mediumfont");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("smallfont");
    }
  });                            
});
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/W6fPE/2/) that I created.

So, my question is could anybody of you show me an HTML version of this one without having to resort to jquery or at least a more shorter version of my jquery code?

Comment: I think you are looking for `nth-child` (which is working both in jQuery as well as pure CSS). See this article for a start: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `td:last-child`

```
.smallfont {font-size:1.0em;}
.mediumfont {font-size:1.5em;}
td { font-size: 1.0em; }
td:last-child { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

Your fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/gG5Lt/

Comment: This will only work (in the sense of the OP) if it's 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks! But how could I be more specific to a class for td:last-child I could not do td.secondtable:last-child nor td:last-child.secondtable ?

Comment: `and the last or 3rd column to be of medium size` - quote from the original OP question. It's a matter of reading ( you've read '3rd column', I've read 'last column'

Comment: Sure, you can. They are all compatible. You can use `last-child` with any class http://jsfiddle.net/gzGk8/

Comment: I got it now. Thanks @drinchev.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 [`:nth-child(`*`index`*`)`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child) selector for this..

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6fPE/3/)

```
td {font-size:1.0em;}
td:nth-child(3) {font-size:1.5em;}
```

Note: Only modern browsers support this property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
td {font-size:1.0em;}
td:nth-child(3n+3) {font-size:1.5em;}
```

Read css3 tricks http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/